# Excel: SUMIF & Weekly totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of entries per day:

[image]

Now I would like to compute the sum of the values in the rows `3` und `4` for each week.

[image]

I tried with

```
=SUMIFS($B$3:$ZZ$3,$B$1:$ZZ$1,">=B7",$B$1:$ZZ$1,"<C7")
```

But I feel that I understand something wrong as both conditions (`">=B7"` and `"<C7"`) are just seen as strings.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the simplest way to accomplish the desired result is just to sum 7 consecutive entries, offset by 7 times the column number:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B$3,0,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,1,7))
```

If you put this in `B8` it will sum `B3:H3` (the first week). If you copy it to `C8`, the `A1` will become a `B1` and then it will sum `I3:O3` (the next week). That way you don't need row 7 at all. Does that answer your question?